# Unable to make UITableViewCell have clear color

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

This is very straightforward. I've tried this a couple of times, in both `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:CellForRow:atIndexPath:`.

Here is my code:

```
cell.alpha = 0.0
cell.backgroundView?.alpha = 0.0
cell.contentView.alpha = 0.0
cell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

I'm pretty sure this should be overkill, but I'm having a really hard time making this work. The cells are being modified inside an if statement because this only applies to certain cells. Yes, I've checked, and the if statement is working as expected. Any ideas?

I am using Xcode version 8.2 beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set:

```
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
```

and also you should provide clear color for whole tableView:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

I've tested in sample project. I create `UIViewController` with `UITableView`. Set the `.red` color for `view` of `UIViewController`. Create `UITableView`, apply `.clear` color for `cell` and `tableView`. You should see the red colored background - so the cells and tableView are transparent.

Here are example screen(The label is added to `.view` of `UIViewController` to make sure that `tableView` is transparent):

[image]